# Delete SOAP Request namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, soap, request, xml-namespaces

I need to delete ns0 prefix contained in fields GRUPPO,AZIENDA,SW_MOD_RICH,NDG but prefix in Object and Costumer need to stay.

```
<ns0:Costumer xmlns:ns0="www.mock.it">
    <ns0:Object>
        <ns0:GRUPPO>string</ns0:GRUPPO>
        <ns0:AZIENDA>string</ns0:AZIENDA>
    </ns0:Object>
</ns0:Costumer>
```

Have you got any ideas? I am struggling to achieve this task.

Thank you for any advice and sorry for bad english.

S

Comment: What tool or library are you using to generate the SOAP message?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: Solved, thank you anyway. it was a problem with generated classes